# Is there a way to duplicate cell from above in Android Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

On Windows the Excel has shortcut `Ctrl+D` which copies the content of the cell from the cell above.

Is there any way to duplicate cell from above in Android Excel without copy/paste? Maybe a kind of menu item or something alike?

**Update**
The only requirement that I need this without external keyboard so that I could use it on my smartphone in "usual way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following steps:

Tap the cell you want to duplicate:

Navigate to the cell where you want to duplicate the content.
Access the editing options:

Look for a menu or toolbar that provides editing options. This might be a toolbar that appears at the top or bottom of the screen.
Find the "Fill" or "Insert" options:

Some versions of Excel for Android have a fill or insert option that allows you to fill a cell with the content from the cell above.
Explore additional options:

Check for additional options in the menu, such as "Fill Down" or "Insert Copied Cells."
Use the context menu:

Long-press on the cell to access a context menu. Look for options like "Fill" or "Insert."
Check for keyboard shortcuts:

Some Android devices support external keyboards. If you're using a keyboard, try using keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+D to see if they work in Excel on Android.

Comment: Thank you. The `Fill` option worked just fine for me.